# Android: Create folder with API 25 ( 7.1.2 )

Tags: android, permissions

Help me please!
My device has just updated to Android 7.1.2 and then my app can not create a folder for first time running.(The code works well with all previous Android versions including 7.1.1).

What I've tried:

- add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE into manifest file

  ```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  ```
- check runtime permission on onCreate()

  ```
  private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION = 1;
  private void checkPermissions() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
          String[] mPermission = {
                              Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
                              Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
          grantPermissions(mPermission);
      } else createFolder("/MyFolder/");
  }

  private void grantPermissions(String[] mPermission) {
      if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[0])
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
          ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, mPermission[1])
          != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, mPermission,REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION);
      } else createFolder("/MyFolder/");
  }

  @Override
  public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
      super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      switch (requestCode) {
          case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION: {
              if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                  if (grantResults.length == 2 &&
                      grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                      grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                      createFolder("/MyFolder/");
                  } else  {Toast.makeText(this, "The app was not allowed to granted some Permissions. So that it cannot function properly. Please consider granting it these permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
              } else  {}
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- create folder function

  ```
  public static void createFolder(String folder) {
      File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + folder;
      File fileFolder = new File(path);
      if (!fileFolder.exists()) 
          Log.e("Utilities","create "+folder+" : "+fileFolder.mkdirs());
  }
  ```

  With 7.1.2, first time running the app, fileFolder.mkdirs() always return false. Restart the app it returns true! Any help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + folder;` should be `String path = root.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +  folder;`. But then we cannot see how you call that function. Please show.

Comment: `createFolder("/MyFolder/");`. Bad design. Dont do such things. Change to `createFolder("MyFolder");`. Only a folder name.

Comment: any help? @greenapps

Comment: No.. Find it a strange story. And i only have 7.1.1.

Comment: thank you anyway @greenapps :)